# Why isn't registerSubmit executed when user submits registration form? spring

Tags: java, html, spring, security

I do not know why **registerSubmit** function is not running when submitting the registration form (register.html), my guess is that it has something to do with how Spring Security works. Even tried with a simple controller method that returns a view, but that is not executed at all, all I see when clicking submit is the same page.

**RegisterController.java**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"/register"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerSubmit(@Valid  User user, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "register";
        }
       User userFound = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());

        if (userFound != null)
        {
            System.out.println("User already in database");
            return "register";
        }

        return "result";

    }
```

**register.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Register Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Register page</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${user}" method="post">

    <table>
        <tr>
           <td> <label for="firstName">First name:</label> </td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" id="firstName" /> </td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:errors="*{firstName}">firstName error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="lastName">Last name:</label> </td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" id="lastName" /></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}" th:errors="*{lastName}">lastName error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="email">email:</label> </td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{email}" id="email" /></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}">email error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>

    </table>


</form>
<a th:href="@{/login}">Login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**SecurityConfig.java**, I've disabled csrf protection as @M. Deinum suggested, but that doesn't work either.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user@mail.com"). password("{noop}pass").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers( "/register", "/login").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/result").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/profile", true)
                    .permitAll()

                    .and()

                .logout()
                        .permitAll();

    }





}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more info about the response the server is sending back?

Comment: @NatFar The server isn’t displaying any error. And the browser is trying to get a response from localhost but loads the same page

Comment: You need to include a csrf token in  your form, or disable csrf in Spring Security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently the register method was stuck here

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "register";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try by adding consuming data type to headers. 

@RequestMapping(
    value = "/register",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    headers="Accept=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
   public String registerSubmit(@Valid  User user, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "register";
        }.....
```

If this is not working you can find more details about your error by using Postman like a tool to send requests and find out what are the accepting request by debugging your server-side code. If there is an issue with spring security such as AuthenticationFailure the error should be logged in the console.

Comment: the server responds with 200 status code to the same page, didn't find any error code